# Binding object to combobox populates list, but selection changes are not updated in the object in CSharp

Tags: c#, binding, combobox

I have a class `ParamObj` (which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`) which contains a property `DefaultValues` of type `ObservableCollection<Param>`. My `Param` class (which also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`) contains two properties: `Name` and `IsSelected`.

On button click I am populating a `StackPanel` with `TextBlock` and `ComboBox` controls. Each `Param` in the collection `DefaultValues` is an option in the `ComboBox`, where the `Name` property represents the text of that option and `IsSelected` is a boolean value representing if that option is the one currently selected in the `ComboBox`.

`Param` class below:

```
public class Param : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public enum ParamType
    {
        Unknown=-1,
        Text=0,
        Option=1,
        Multi=2
    }

    private string pName = string.Empty;
    private bool pSelected = false;
    private ParamType pType = ParamType.Unknown;

    public string Name { get { return pName; } set { pName = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } }
    public bool IsSelected { get { return pSelected; } set { pSelected = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected"); } }
    public ParamType Type { get { return pType; } }

    public Param(string name, bool selected)
    {
        this.pName = name;
        this.pSelected = selected;
        this.pType = ParamType.Option;
    }

    //INotifyPropertyChanged base
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

`ParamObj` class below:

```
public class ParamObj : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //ui type mapping
    public enum UITypeEnum
    {
        Textbox = 0,
        ComboBox = 1,
        CheckableComboBox = 2
    }

    private string name = string.Empty;
    private UITypeEnum uiType = UITypeEnum.Textbox;
    private ObservableCollection<Param> defaultVals = new ObservableCollection<Param>();
    private string propDescription = string.Empty;

    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } }
    public UITypeEnum UIType { get { return uiType; } set { uiType = value; OnPropertyChanged("UIType"); } }
    public ObservableCollection<Param> DefaultValues { get { return defaultVals; } }
    public string Desc { get { return propDescription; } set { propDescription = value; } }

    //Initialization
    public ParamObj()
    {

    }

    public void ClearDefaultValues()
    {
        this.defaultVals.Clear();
        OnPropertyChanged("DefaultValues");
    }

    public void AddDefaultValue(Param objAdded)
    {
        this.defaultVals.Add(objAdded);
    }

    public void AddDefaultValueRange(Param[] objsToAdd)
    {
        foreach (Param o in objsToAdd)
        {
            this.defaultVals.Add(o);
        }
    }

    //INotifyPropertyChanged base
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Code below is called in the button click event. `po` represents a `ParamObj` instance.

```
case ParamObj.UITypeEnum.ComboBox:
    cb = new ComboBox();
    cb.Height = 26;
    cb.Width = 210;
    cb.Margin = new Thickness(2);
    cb.VerticalContentAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
    cb.DataContext = po.DefaultValues;
    //binding
    cb.ItemsSource = po.DefaultValues;
    cb.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";                        
    cb.SelectedValuePath = "IsSelected";
    cb.SelectedValue = true;

    cb.SelectionChanged += ParamComboBox_SelectionChanged;
    break;
```

Here's the problem. `ComboBox` items are populated successfully and the option (`Param` object) that has an `IsSelected` value of `true` is selected. What I thought would happen is that when I changed the selected option in the `ComboBox` the `IsSelected` property's value (boolean) of the `Param` object would be toggled from `false` to `true`. This didn't happen. So I added the `cb.SelectionChanged += ParamComboBox_SelectionChanged` event to the `ComboBox`.

```
    private void ParamComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(sender is ComboBox)) return;

        ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
        Param cp = (Param)cb.SelectedItem;
        if (cp.IsSelected == false)
        {
            foreach (Param p in cb.ItemsSource)
            {
                p.IsSelected = false;
            }
            cp.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
```

Through debugging I do see that the `IsSelected` properties are correctly updated, but the values in my `po` object are not updated with the new values.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. I've tried my darndest to figure this out but I'm stuck.

Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the problems that appear to be very simple, but seems like there is no easy or direct way to bind the ComboBoxItem IsSelected to a given property. One possible solution that comes to my mind could be:

First, Add a Style of type ComboBoxItem to your ComboBox and add a Trigger to that style. This trigger will fire when you have selected a ComboBoxItem and will call the helper class in step 2.

```
     <ComboBox Name="TestCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataSource.DefaultValues}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="IsSelected" SelectionChanged="Test_SelectionChanged">
                <ComboBox.Resources>                    
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="StackOverflow:IsSelectedBehavior.IsSelected" Value="True"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="StackOverflow:IsSelectedBehavior.IsSelected" Value="False"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.Resources>
            </ComboBox>
```

If you want to do this same thing programmatically, then you go:

```
        Style style = new Style();
        Trigger t = new Trigger();
        style.TargetType = typeof(ComboBoxItem);
        t.Property = ListBoxItem.IsSelectedProperty;
        t.Value = true;
        Setter setter = new Setter(IsSelectedBehavior.IsSelectedProperty, true);
        t.Setters.Add(setter);
        style.Triggers.Add(t);
        cb.Resources.Add(typeof(ComboBoxItem), style);
```

Then, Create a IsSelectedBehaviorClass to handle your IsSelected Behavior. This static class will receive the currently selected ComboBoxItem and set the Param.IsSelected property accordingly.  Something like this:

```
    public static class IsSelectedBehavior
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsSelected", typeof (bool), typeof (IsSelectedBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsSelected));

        public static bool GetIsSelected(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool) d.GetValue(IsSelectedProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsSelected(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value);
        }

        public static void OnIsSelected(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Get current ComboBoxItem
            ComboBoxItem test = d as ComboBoxItem;
            //Get the current Param from the ComboBoxItem.Content
            Param p = test.Content as Param;
            //Set the Param.IsSelected property
            p.IsSelected = (bool) e.NewValue;
        }
    }
```

Finally you can test your solution on the SelectionChanged EventHandler

```
    private void ParamComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Param selected = cb.SelectedItem as Param;
            if (selected != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Selection Changed: Selected " + selected.Name);
            }
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var obj in cb.Items)
            {
                Param p = obj as Param;
                str.Append("Name:" + p.Name + " IsSelected:" + p.IsSelected + Environment.NewLine);
                Debug.WriteLine(str);
            }
            MessageBox.Show(str.ToString());
        }
```